# How to view complete text of Mercurial commit messages in TortoiseHg Workbench

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, tortoisehg-2.0, mercurial-commit

Is it possible to view the full text of a Mercurial commit message from TortoiseHg Workbench.

Presently, only the description column and the snippet exposed in the Changeset expansion seem to show commit text. And even they only appear to show the summary portion of the messages.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's actually possible to collapse the full commit message, see the screenshots below how to expand it again.

[image: Before expanding]
[image: After expanding]

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine, there you found problem in WorkBench. Screenshot with active long multiline commit-message changeset added as example

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Yes,

Click on View -> Revision Details 
(Or click on the person + small white document) icon.

This should show the full commit message, to the right of the list of changed files panel.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the fact that the commit message text area is collapsed by default and the bar to expand it is almost invisible. Look at larsm's answer for a screenshot: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15829695/661517